# Very new to java, stumped with no main classesfound

Tags: java

I'm very new to java, and for an assignment, I had to write a code using if-else statements and user input. But when I go running the code it says there is no main class found until I remove the if-else statement.

```
package userinput2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class userinput2 {

    public static void main(String[] args, String yes) {

        // auto close scanner
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            System.out.print("What is your name? ");

            String input = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input

            System.out.println("Hi " + input);              

           System.out.print("Do you like classical music? ");

            String input2 = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input

                        if (input2.equals(yes)) {
             System.out.println("Good for you.");
            }
            else{                   
            System.out.println("Nice meeting you " + input);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.

Comment: Why is there "try" there? You realize "try" requires a "catch" block, which you haven't written?

Comment: thanks for letting me know

Comment: the *main* method must only have one parameter, so you should remove the _String yes_ parameter

Comment: Like i said im very new and am going based off what i can learn on the internet. So i dont know what a catch block is

Comment: @Flat that is a `try-with-resources` statement ([JLS 14.20.3. try -with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3))- it does not require a `catch` block // @Tyler you really don't need it there, it closes the `Scanner` (at end) which will close `System.in`, normally not a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it for you. Notice

### main(String[] args)

Main method must have only 1 param.
If you use **try{** you shall also *catch the exception*. (And handle it aswell)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try{
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What is your name? "); 
        String input = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input

        System.out.println("Hi " + input);              

        System.out.print("Do you like classical music? ");

        String input2 = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input
        if (input2.equals("yes")) 
        System.out.println("Good for you.");
        else                  
        System.out.println("Nice meeting you " + input);

     }catch(Exception mainException){
      //HANDLE Exception Part
      mainException.printStackTrace();

    }
   }
```

Comment: thank you so much, i'll make sure to compare the two to see exactly what you changed